# Installing MySQL 5.5.19 with Macports

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

The MySQL packages currently available on Macports are up to date for branch 5.1, but for 5.5 they are quite old (the latest one available is 5.5.2).

Is there some way to install the latest one at this moment (5.5.19)? Why is the package so old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacPorts has a wiki where they explain how to upgrade any port to the latest available version. Here it is: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/Upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Why insist on macports? Can you not download the most recent version from mysql.com and install it? I did and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: This is obviously not a solution to the question, but a workaround. I'm asking to USE Macports.